# Errors with UwAmp PHP 7

Tags: php, wordpress, uwamp

I get errors with some WordPress themes (Layers and Dynamic Website Builder) when using UwAmp and versions of PHP 7.  With Layers there is an error about an empty category array and with Dynamic Website Builder, the admin pages cannot be reached (connection reset).

I have UwAmp 3.1 and have tried PHP 7.0.3 and PHP 7.1.1.  There are no errors with PHP 5.6.18.

I installed the Visual Studio redistributable when I installed UwAmp.  At first, I thought it was a problem with the Themes and maybe PHP 7.1.1, but I tried PHP 7.0.7 using the Uniform Server and those themes worked fine.  That lead me to conclude it is more likely related to UwAmp.

There are no related errors in the Apache log and even though logging is enabled for PHP and I specified a log file in the INI file, there are no PHP error logs. I have not enabled or disabled any PHP extensions.

I suspect it may be something missing from the UwAmp versions of PHP 7.x.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So it is not an issue with UwAmp.  I found that there was a change with PHP 7.1 where empty string arrays must be initialized.  Previously PHP would handle it automagically.  You can see a discussion of it here:  https://github.com/spotweb/spotweb/issues/243